# Stop netcat when VirtualBox closes

Tags: shell-script, networking, virtualbox, printing

Using netcat to redirect print output from DOS program in VirtualBox under OSX.

```
#!/bin/bash
VBoxManage startvm FreeDOS
while :
do
    nc -l 1235 | lpr
done
```

This works except that when VirtualBox closes netcat keeps running.
There must be a better way!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by:

1. Backgrounding your nc | lpr pipeline
2. Polling the status of the VM
3. Kill the backgrounded pipeline when the VM dies.

Luckily, VBoxManage provides a way to do (3). VBoxManage has a `showvminfo` command that can give you the current state of a vm.

```
VBoxManage startvm FreeDOS

(
    while :
    do
        nc -l 1235 | lpr
    done
)&


while sleep 10; do
    vmstate=$(VBoxManage showvminfo --machinereadable FreeDOS | awk -F= '{ if ($1=="VMState") print $2}' | tr -d '"')
    case $vmstate in
        running)
            echo "Still running."
            ;;
        *)
            echo "VM not running. Attempting to kill netcat"
            kill %%
            exit 0;
    esac
done
```

Note that currently this only handles "running" vs everything else.  There might be other states you might want to account for in the case statement.  You can potentially simplify the first while loop by using netcat's -k argument as well (so that you don't have to loop at all).

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. tnc in guest gets connection but it shuts down due to signal from host. nc is not cleaned up. A bit beyond my skills but will keep looking.

Comment: Added the O/S to the question (OS/X).

Comment: nc without -k accepts file from guest and sends it immediately to lpr and closes down. With -k option nc increases in size with each file sent from guest and doesn't close, but doesn't output anything. Bug? Or is there some way to tell it different?

Comment: With the nc backgrounded without the | lpr pipe the guest is unable to connect and the job is not closed on guest close, but the job can be manually killed.

Comment: With the nc | lpr backgrounded the print queue is open awaiting input, guest is unable to connect. On closing guest script exits with lpr: No file in print request. Running script again when guest closes the script terminates leaving nc and lpr processes open for some seconds, upon which they terminate and the no file in print request appears at the terminal. Very confusing!!

Comment: Actually in either the above two cases the nc process terminates after approx 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I give up!
Solved the connect problems by using ncat instead of nc and abandoned the backgrounding thing as I just couldn't get it to work. The following works and shuts down the processes on exit.

```
if VBoxManage startvm FreeDOS; then    
    if ! pgrep ncat -p 1235 -l ; then
        while :
        do
            ncat -p 1235 -l | lpr
        done
    fi
fi
```